# Grid is not working as expected python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I am working on a program where it makes a checker board layout. With spacing between the checkerboard layout. But recently I have run into a problem where it stopped the grid from making its self into a grid and all of the frames are just going in row 0 and column 0.

Can someone explain to me why it has suddenly started doing this?

```
 def fields(self):
    frame_row = 0 #Frame row value
    frame_column = 0 #Frame column value
    row_count = 0

    note_title = ""
    note_sum = ""

    for i in range(len(self.fileNames)):
        fileName = self.fileNames[i]
        fileTitle = open("Files/" + fileName, "r")
        title = fileTitle.read()
        fileTitle.close()

        note_title = title[:20]
        note_sum = title[:100]

        self.bfr2.columnconfigure(frame_column, pad=10)
        self.bfr2.rowconfigure(frame_row, pad=10)

        self.frame = Frame(self.bfr2, bg="pink", width=229, height=105, cursor="hand2", name="frame") #This is the frame widget. That si ahving problems being positioned.
        self.frame.grid(row=frame_row, column=frame_column)
        self.frame.pack_propagate(False)

        self.sum = Label(self.frame, text=note_sum.replace("\n", " "), width=32, height=5, anchor=NW, wraplength=230, justify=LEFT, name="summNote")
        self.sum.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.sum.pack_propagate(False)

        self.x = Label(self.sum, text="X", bg="red", width=2)
        self.x.pack(anchor=NE)

        self.noteName = Label(self.frame, font=("Arial", 12), text=note_title.replace("\n", ""), anchor=W, bg="grey", name="noteName")
        self.noteName.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        frame_column = frame_column + 1
        row_count = row_count + 1

        if row_count == 2:
            frame_row = frame_row + 1
            frame_column = 0
            row_count = 0
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried printing out the row and column values at the time you're calling grid?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I have and they where the row and column values that they were supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `name` parameter in this line:

```
self.frame = Frame(self.bfr2, ..., name="frame")
```

You're creating three frames, and giving them each the same name. Tkinter uses this name internally as the name of the widget. Because of this, you create a widget with the internal name of something like `.bfr2.frame`. Then, you create the next widget, also with the name `.bfr2.frame`. This causes the original widget to be destroyed and replaced with the new widget. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Each time you create a widget in the same parent with the same `name` parameter, the previous widget with the same name is destroyed.

If you want to use the `name` parameter, it must be unique for each widget.